# How do you ask the User multiple questions in C?

Tags: c

I am new to "C programming" and I have Googled for my answer, but I can't seem to get what I am looking for. I am making a simple 2 question program. The code is listed below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char characterName[] = "Mike";
    int age = 0;

    printf("Enter your age, %s.\n", characterName);
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Your being %d is old older than me and my brother "
           "which was the first computer.Hahaaa.... \n", age);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the next question:

```
char str[50];
{
    printf("Anything to say about my comment? \n");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", str);
    printf("That was a good answer. I wasn't expecting that from you.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a function to ask a question, and return a response?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Prompt the user with the given question, return their
 * input in answer, up to max_answer_length bytes 
 * returns 1 for ok, 0 on error.
 */
int askQuestion(const char *question, char *answer, const size_t max_answer_length)
{
    int input_ok = 1;  

    // Show the user the question
    printf( "%s: ", question );

    // Throw away any existing input in the user's input-queue
    // (like if they answered with a really-long string previously)
    fflush(stdin);

    // Read a line of input from the user into <answer>, but not more
    // than <max_answer_length>-1 bytes are accepted (see fgets() for details)
    // If the fgets() returns EOF or an error, make sure we remember it
    if ( fgets( answer, max_answer_length, stdin ) == NULL )
        input_ok = 0;

    // return whether there was an error on input
    return input_ok;
}

int main(void)
{
    char answer_buffer[200];

    askQuestion( "What is your favourite fruit?", answer_buffer, sizeof(answer_buffer) );
    printf( ">> %s\n", answer_buffer );

    askQuestion( "How long have you been programming C?", answer_buffer, sizeof(answer_buffer) );
    printf( ">> %s\n", answer_buffer );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I will review what you wrote and comment once I have taken a look and understood what you have provided me with. Thanks again.

Comment: There's an input-flow-on bug here if the user enters more than `sizeof(answer_buffer)` letters in their answer.  It can be fixed with a `fflush()`

Comment: Thanks that code worked. Although, I have no "idea" what sizeof,buffer is I am going to try to break down the code. Thanks a million!

Comment: Looking for help and clarification.

We have created a Function called askQuestion, right?

We want the questions, answer, and size to not be changed.  Can you help me with the middle part of the Function? I am not quite understanding it.

Comment: @Kudosarehere - I added some comments, did that clarify it ?  The `stdin` is the file-handle from the user's console.  So say you do a `scanf( ... )`, this is equivalent to `fscanf( stdin, ...)`.  The handles `stdin` and `stdout` are the read+write of the user's console.

Comment: Kingsley, that help very much!